# CSS class in html is overridden by class not in html

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I am baffled by a situation with my code where I am trying to affect the appearance of a list, depending on the parent class. I currently have 2 different looks for 2 different parents. However, when 1 parent class is written in the HTML I don't get that look instead I get the other class that is in the CSS only.

I have researched specificity and cascading and I have an okay understanding of both. With my knowledge I think my code should work as it is written regardless of the cascade or order in the CSS. From what I gather my class rule set has the same specificity but different parent classes, and I would think that the parent class would be applied and not overridden by the subsequent parent class in the CSS.

```css
.bg-brown .listing-article li {
  border: 1px #a37457 solid;
}

.bg-blue .listing-article li {
  border: 1px #729bad solid;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg-brown">
  <div>
    <ul class="listing-article">
      <li>
        <h2>Article Title</h2>
        <div>
          <p>Summary Text</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>Published: </li>
            <li>Categories: </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

So what I get with bg-brown is a list with a blue border not a brown. What I would like to know is, why is .bg-blue taking precedence over .bg-brown when it isn't being called in the HTML?

What is even more baffling is when I put .bg-blue before .bg-brown in the CSS they work correctly, even when I switch the HTML class from brown to blue in the HTML. I would think it would produce the same result just a brown border instead of blue.

Comment: "I would think it would produce the same result just a brown border instead of blue." — It does. You forgot to verify your [mcve]

Comment: Your code doesn't reproduce the problem you're describing. `.bg-blue` isn't doing anything. https://jsfiddle.net/31otehvy/

Comment: @Michael_B I guess the real problem of OP is he has the `bg-blue` assigned to a prev parent, this fiddle can replicate the actual description of the post https://jsfiddle.net/31otehvy/1/

Comment: @DaniP - The JS fiddle is not right, because I do not have a parent element with a class of .bg-blue on with a .bg-brown child. The 2 color classes only change the background color of the parent element.

Comment: @Michael_B that fiddle is what I expected to happen with the code. However, I am not getting a result like that locally. Which resulted in my question.

Comment: The only thing we have to work with is the code you provided. As you can see, everything works as expected. If you're getting a different outcome on your site, there's something else in play. You can revise your question with more code, or you can hit F12 when on your browser (in Windows) to launch the inspector and check the code yourself.

Comment: Upon looking at my code again. @DaniP your fiddle was the right, I did have a parent class of bg-blue. It just wasn't immediately outside the section container. It was on the body tag closer to the top of the page and in my header file. Which makes sense why it is getting overruled.